# сравнить строки в forth

Tags: forth

ввожу с клавиатуры две строки, затем надо их сравнить.
compare никогда не возвращает 0(строки никогда не равны, даже если одинаковые значения):

```
First word:
de
Second word:
de
<1> 1
```

помогите найти, что не так

```
CREATE word1 14 ALLOT
: .getword1 word1 14 BLANK word1 14 EXPECT ;


CREATE word2 14 ALLOT
: .getword2 word2 14 BLANK word2 14 EXPECT ;

: input_words
." " CR
." First word:" CR
.getword1
." " CR
." Second word:" CR
.getword2
word1
word2
word2 word1 compare
.s
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17381241/4827341

Comment: со строками, которые объявляются как s" hello" всё норм, а с моими с клавами не получается((

Answer (score 1):

> помогите найти, что не так

1. Проверяйте, какие аргументы должны быть у используемых слов.

У слова [`COMPARE`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/string/COMPARE) на входе две пары `(адрес длина)`, каждая из которых задает строку, на выходе код `-1|0|1`, стековая сигнатура: `( addr1 u1  addr2 u2 -- n )`.

2. Выполняйте код определения интерактивно, в консоли. Например:

```
.getword1 .s
.getword2 .s
word1 word2 word2 word1 .s
compare .s
```

(если Форт-система выводит состояние стека, то `.s` не нужно)

3. Поначалу, пишите стековый комментарий в каждой значимой строке кода (в виде состояния стека после выполнения этой строки). И всегда — стековую сигнатуру определяемого слова.

```
: input_words ( -- n )
  ." " CR
  ." First word:" CR
  .getword1 ( )
  ." " CR
  ." Second word:" CR
  .getword2 ( )
  word1 ( addr1 )
  word2 ( addr1 addr2 )
  word2 word1 ( addr1 addr2  addr2 addr1 )
  compare ( n )
  .s
;
```

4. Используйте современную стандартную Forth-систему. Вместо [`EXPECT`](http://forth.sourceforge.net/standard/fst83/fst83-12.htm#expect) и [`SPAN`](http://forth.sourceforge.net/standard/fst83/fst83-12.htm#span) — [`ACCEPT`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/ACCEPT).

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали под какой Форт системой запускаете приводимый код.
К примеру, под gForth приведённый пример отработал нормально.

P.S. Для проверки данных в памяти полезно может быть использование слова
DUMP ( addr len -- )

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1490951/edit)».